# Problem of simplification

Tags: systems-of-equations, lambert-w

When trying to solve the equation $y^y = \frac{\ln^{y(1+c)}n}{n}$ , I've found the result
$$y=\frac{-\ln n}{W(-\ln^{-c}n)}$$
where $c$ is a positive constant and $W$ is the Lambert function.

The result should be positive, and the result I obtain seems to be positive, but I don't like the form.

Is it possible to obtain a better form for this result ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: May be, you could post the equation. The form is beautiful.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I've added it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici In fact, I don't like the negative signs.

Comment: Be more tolerant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @martycohen. Do you want to say that I should be satisfied with such a  form ?

Comment: If you change $n$ to $1/n$, the minus signs go away. The original equation becomes $y^y = n\ln^{y(1+c)}(1/n)$ and the result is $y=\frac{\ln n}{W(\ln^{-c}n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could rewrite the last line as

$$y=e^{W(-\ln^{-c}n)}$$

$$=e^{W\left(\frac{-1}{\ln^cn}\right)}$$

For clarity, I'm going to write the stuff inside the $W$,

$$\frac{-1}{\ln^cn}=\frac1{\left(e^{\frac\pi ci}\ln(n)\right)^c}$$

$$y=e^{W\left(\frac1{\left(e^{\frac\pi ci}\ln(n)\right)^c}\right)}$$

Got rid of the negatives?